# SpringSecurity: hasRole does not work after set config?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

this is my Java Config:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("Jon")
                  .password("123456")
                  .roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("Bob")
                  .password("qwer")
                  .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")

                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()

                .httpBasic()
        ;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I hava to peroson

- Jon, has role as  `USER`
- Bob, has roles as `USER` `ADMIN`

But, so Jon should not hava permition to visis `/admin/**`, then I write follow test

```
        ResultMatcher isUnauthorized = MockMvcResultMatchers.status()
                .is(401);

        String credential = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("Jon:123456".getBytes());

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/admin/")
                        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + credential);

        mockMvc.perform(builder)
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(isUnauthorized);
```

I expect this test return 401 unauthorized, But actually it return 200.

What is the problem?

SpringSecurityVersion is `5.1.5.RELEASE`

Comment: Is your configuration executed? Did you add an breakpoint in your `configure` method?

Comment: @dur yes, friend, both configure was executed, some I am very confused

Comment: Do you get still 200, if you change the credentials to a wrong value (wrong user or password)?

Comment: @dur yes, still get 200 with wrong password.....     I will check and debug again, thanks

Comment: You don't show your test annotations. Verify that you have enabled spring-security for your tests. ([see examples here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests)). If you are using `@SpringBootTest` then you will need `.apply(springSecurity())` on your MockMvc builder.